# MS SQL server cast on table joins

Tags: casting

I have a table that contains postcodes for customers, these are stored as type nvarchar and contain a mix of alphanumeric e.g. 'YO41 1LZ' and numeric e.g. 12345 postcodes. I also have a table that contains valid postcodes supplied by the courier company we use to deliver goods. Their data is stored with a postcode1 and postcode2 in each row. These values are ranges within which all the postcodes are valid e.g. postcode1 = 1234 and postcode2 = 2345 so 2321 is valid, but 1231 is not. These rows also contain alphanumeric values such as 'YO41' and are stored as type varchar.

I want to link to this table so that when I query company details including the address, it also returns a bit flag for whether the postcode we have stored is compatible with the list the courier company has supplied. A simplified version of the query I've written is below.

The problem is that when the postcode is numeric, I need to do a numeric comparison of the postcodes, but when alphanumeric a string comparison. The query below throws the error "Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'YO41 1LZ' to data type int." I think the problem must be the way I'm using CAST. Does anyone know of a better way of doing this please?

```
SELECT
  company.companyname,
  address.line1,
  address.line2,
  address.postcode,
  CASE
  WHEN courierpostcodes.postcodeid IS NOT NULL
  THEN 1
  ELSE 0
  END AS postcodeValid
FROM
  company
  JOIN address
    ON company.companyid = address.companyid
    LEFT OUTER JOIN courierpostcodes
      ON (ISNUMERIC(courierpostcodes.postcode1) = 1 AND ISNUMERIC(address.postcode) = 1
              AND CAST(address.postcode AS int) BETWEEN CAST(courierpostcodes.postcode1 AS int) AND CAST(courierpostcodes.postcode2 AS int))

              OR 

              ((ISNUMERIC(courierpostcodes.postcode1) = 0 OR ISNUMERIC(address.postcode) = 0)
              AND CAST(address.postcode AS nvarchar) BETWEEN CAST(courierpostcodes.postcode1 AS nvarchar) AND CAST(courierpostcodes.postcode2 AS nvarchar))
WHERE
  company.id = *mycompanyid*
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a much better approach is to store all of the valid postcodes in a table directly, rather than as ranges.  This allows you to do a *proper* foreign-key relationship, which I expect will be much more efficient, as well as allow you to keep more of your sanity.